# Sharepoint people-picker with external domain trust

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, active-directory

I have a MOSS 2007 server in an environment with both a two way cross forest trust and a two way external trust. Users in the forest-trusted forest happily show up in peoplepicker, but I get nothing out of the external trust.

I've tried a variety of different options for the peoplepicker-searchadforests property with no luck. SSP can import the profiles okay, and I've logged on as the service account and verified I can query users in the external domain.

Has anyone successfully configured sharepoint to query users via a two-way external trust? Is there something I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

The external trust has been changed to a forest trust and still has the same issue. Network Monitor is showing the LDAP query occurring against the remote DC and responses being returned, but there's still nothing showing up in peoplepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosts file on the WFE was edited to redirect DC queries to a local DC replica, and this worked. Unsure if the problem was due to incompatibility with the remote (Server 2003) DCs, or some issue with the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have done it in the past.  Had to set the peoplepicker-searchadforests even though you are not supposed to have to do that with two way trusts.

Comment: Thanks JD - I've been reduced to using Network Monitor on the WFE to make sure the LDAP queries are going through. peoplepicker-searchadforests seems to trigger queries to the correct servers, and I can see the LDAP response coming back, but Sharepoint appears to be ignoring it.